# VirtualBox error: Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) chromebook

Tags: chromebook

download software and download gnome-boxes ctrl n and then pick what which file you want on virtual box. Virtual box, docker, and other platforms will not work on Chromebook or least the free ones.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, please read this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; only details about your hardware (a chromebook).  You should start with what Ubuntu product you're actually using, ie. Ubuntu Core, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, what release of whichever product you're using etc.